# How to replace string by regex

Tags: android, json, regex

I would like to replace a json string from:

```
[{"id":151,"name":"me"}, {"id":4567432,"name":"you"}]
```

to:

```
[{"id":"151","name":"me"}, {"id":"4567432","name":"you"}]
```

As you can see, I just want to add parentheses to the id's value(some number).

I tried:

```
json = json.replaceAll("\"id\",([0-9]+)", "\"id\",\"$1\"");
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: "...I just want to add parentheses..." They are double quotes, not parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using commas as key-value separator, but in the sample string, you have a colon.

You can fix the replaceAll method if you use

```java
replaceAll("(\"id\":)([0-9]+)", "$1\"$2\"")
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Cvx2L/1).

*Details*:

- `(\"id\":)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `"id":` string
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more digits

Comment: Wow, perfect! King! :)

Answer (score 0):

with js code

```js
// #js code

const data = [{"id":151,"name":"me"}, {"id":4567432,"name":"you"}];

function solve1(data) {
  // solution 1
  // with stringify data
  const getMatches = data.match(/\"id\"\:\d+\,/gi);
  getMatches?.forEach((theMatch)=>{
    const getNumbers = theMatch.match(/\d+/gi).join("");
    const newMatch = theMatch.replace(getNumbers,`"${getNumbers}"`);
    data = data.replace(theMatch,newMatch)
  })
  return data;
}
function solve2(data) {

  // solution 2
  // with json data
  return data.map((item)=>{
    item.id = item.id.toString(); 
    return item;
  })
}
console.log(solve1(JSON.stringify(data)));
console.log(solve2(data))
```